# Ruby each do loop 'n' number of times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

Hi I'm having trouble with the below loop in a .erb view

```
<% my_list.each do | list | %>
.. loop stuff.....
<% end %.
```

This works fine for looping through my list, but I only want to loop through the first 4 items in 'my_list' and not the whole list. I tried some things like:

```
<% my_list.each do | product |  3.times %>
```

but didn't seem to work as I think my ruby knowledge is limited to say the least!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take first 4 element from `my_list` [Array#first](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/first):

```
<% my_list.first(4).each do | product |  %>
```

use [Array#each_slice](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each%5fslice) for slice your array

```
<% my_list.each_slice(4) do | products |  %>
  <% products.each do | product |  %>
```

Comment: thanks, how would I then loop from Number 5 in the list

Answer (score 5):

Use [Array#take](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-take) like this:

```
<% my_list.take(4).each do | product | %>
```

Comment: great , worked thanks, AS an aside, how would I then loop through the next group of items something like take (4+1)

Answer (score 2):

It is apparent that you want to iterate through your list in groups of four (you really should amend your question, because this is an important piece of information). It is also apparent you are using Rails. Fortunately Rails has `in_groups_of` built into ActiveSupport:

```
<% my_list.in_groups_of(4) do |products| %>
  <% products.each do | product | %>
```

One advantage of this approach (over alternatives such as `each_slice`) is that `in_groups_of` will pad the end to make sure you *always* get four groups. It will pad with `nil` by default, but you can specify the padding yourself:

```
<% my_list.in_groups_of(4, "&nbsp;") do |products| %>
```

If you pass `false` as the pad, it will not pad at all and behaves just like `each_slice`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% my_list[0..3].each do | list | %>
```